# Flutter column не отображает элементы

Tags: flutter

Когда Column, элементы в листе не отображаются, а если использовать Row, то   отображается.

```
Widget _buildRow(Banner banner) {
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(banner.title),
          Expanded(
            child: Image.network(banner.image)
          )
        ],
      ),
    )
  );}
```

Comment: Виджет называется _buildRow, а вы делаете Column. Вы точно нигде не ошиблись? Какие элементы в листе? Где код с листом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, решение такое?

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: banner.length,
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) => Card(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text(banner[index].title),
      Image.network(banner[index].image)
    ],
  ),
),
```